# Mockito MissingMethodInvocationException when I try to run my Cucumber StepDef

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to use Mockito mocks in my Cucumber Step Defs, but somehow it won't work.
I get the same *org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException* every time.

The code is simple.

```
  @Rule
  public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Mock
  public PlayDeck mockDeck = new PlayDeck(6);

  @Mock
  public Hand hand = new Hand(this.mockDeck);

  @Angenommen("ich habe eine Karo {int} auf der Hand mit dem Wert {int}")
  public void ich_habe_eine_Karo_auf_der_Hand_mit_dem_Wert(final Integer int1, final Integer int2) {
    //given
    Mockito.when(this.mockDeck.drawCard())
        .thenReturn(Card.builder().color(CardColor.Diamond).face(getFaceByValue(int1)).build());
    //when
    this.hand.draw();
    //then
    Assertions.assertThat(this.hand.value()).isEqualTo(int2);
  }
```

But everytime I run it, it fails. The Documentation says: *when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.* But my when(...) does have a Method inside.

I also tried to use BDDMockito

```
BDDMockito.given(this.mockDeck.drawCard())
        .willReturn(
            Card.builder().color(CardColor.Diamond).face(getFaceByValue(int1)).build());
```

Same error. But in my Unit tests, it works just fine. For example here:

```
@Rule public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock public PlayDeck mockDeck = new PlayDeck(8);

@Mock public Hand mockHand = new Hand(this.mockDeck);

@Test public void returnFalseIfBusted() {
    //given
    given(this.mockDeck.drawCard())
            .willReturn(Card.builder().color(CardColor.Heart).face(CardFace.KING).build());
    final Hand hand = new Hand(this.mockDeck);
    //when
    hand.draw();
    //then
    assertThat(hand.isBusted()).isTrue();
}
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Rules don't work with Cucumber